# How to render jade templates into HTML using brunch

Tags: javascript, pug, brunch

Trying to use brunch for my new project. One thing I want to do is being able to write all my HTML assets in jade and have brunch render it into HTML during the build. I found the jaded-brunch, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make it do what I want. Here is my config.

```
exports.config =
    paths:
        watched: ['client']

    npm:
        enabled: true
        packages: ['react']

    plugins:
        jaded:
            jade:
                pretty: yes
    files:
        javascripts:
            joinTo:
                'js/app.js': /^app/
                'js/vendor.js': /^(?!app)/
        stylesheets:
            joinTo: 'css/app.css'

    templates:
        joinTo: 'index.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but Brunch has been updated to handle static asset compilation a bit more gracefully.

The [official `jade-brunch` package](https://github.com/brunch/jade-brunch) takes care of business with no additional config.

Placing your `.jade` files in your `app/assets` directory (or wherever you've set your static basedir to) compiles the jade files as static HTML.

If you're using includes/extends and you don't want a bunch of partial HTML files in your `public` directory, naming them with a preceding underscore tells Brunch to ignore those files. If your `app` directory looks like this:

```
app
  | assets
  |  | index.jade
  |  | partials
  |  |   | _header.jade
```

...and your `index.jade` includes `_header`:

```
include partials/_header
```

your `public` directory will look like this:

```
public
  | index.html
```

Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [jaded-brunch documentation](https://github.com/monokrome/jaded-brunch#usage), you can tell it to compile jade files into static html output either by naming them all with a `.static.jade` file extension, or set the `staticPatterns` option, like:

```
plugins:
    jaded:
        staticPatterns: /\.jade$/
        jade:
            pretty: yes
```

Comment: Does't work. I get this "'client/index.static.jade' compiled, but not written. Check your templates.joinTo config" and no files appear in public.

Comment: @MadWombat try removing `templates.joinTo`.